# Compact Framework - how do I dynamically create type with no default constructor?

Tags: c#, reflection, compact-framework

I'm using the .NET CF 3.5. The type I want to create does not have a default constructor so I want to pass a string to an overloaded constructor. How do I do this?

Code:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("my.dll");
Type t = a.GetType("type info here");
// All ok so far, assembly loads and I can get my type

string s = "Pass me to the constructor of Type t";
MyObj o = Activator.CreateInstance(t); // throws MissMethodException
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MyObj o = null;
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("my.dll");
Type t = a.GetType("type info here");

ConstructorInfo ctor = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
if(ctor != null)
   o = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { s });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's a funky helper method to give you a flexible way to activate a type given an array of parameters:

```
static object GetInstanceFromParameters(Assembly a, string typeName, params object[] pars) 
{
    var t = a.GetType(typeName);

    var c = t.GetConstructor(pars.Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray());
    if (c == null) return null;

    return c.Invoke(pars);
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
Foo f = GetInstanceFromParameters(a, "SmartDeviceProject1.Foo", "hello", 17) as Foo;
```

So you pass the assembly and the name of the type as the first two parameters, and then all the constructor's parameters in order.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you (untested):

```
Type t = a.GetType("type info here");
var ctors = t.GetConstructors();
string s = "Pass me to the ctor of t";
MyObj o = ctors[0].Invoke(new[] { s }) as MyObj;
```

If the type has more than one constructor then you may have to do some fancy footwork to find the one that accepts your string parameter.

Edit: Just tested the code, and it works.

Edit2: [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436/compact-framework-how-do-i-dynamically-create-type-with-no-default-constructor#29472) shows the fancy footwork I was talking about! ;-)