# instantiate an object from a user-defined assembly

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compact Framework - how do I dynamically create type with no default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436/compact-framework-how-do-i-dynamically-create-type-with-no-default-constructor)

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 CF project for Windows CE 6.

I use Assembly.LoadFrom() to load a "plug-in" .net assembly specified by the user. 
I would like to use [System.Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to instantiate an object defined in that assembly. But the only overload of CreateInstance() available in .net CF takes no parameters and the constructor I'd like to load requires them.

```
namespace System
{   
    public sealed class Activator
    {
        public static T CreateInstance<T>();
        public static object CreateInstance(Type type);
    }
}
```

How can I instantiate an object whose constructor takes a parameter in .net CF 3.5?

Thanks,
PaulH