# C# Winform dynamically load usercontrols by name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, compact-framework

I want to know if it's possible to dynamically load user controls?
This is some code to show what I mean:

```
public void Load()
        {

            Reset();

            if (_host.User == null)
                return;

            int _count = 0;

            String[] _applications = _host.User.Applications;

            if (_applications == null)
                return;

            foreach (String _application in _applications)
            {

                TabPage _page = null;

                switch (_application)
                {
                    case "SF01":

                        _page = new TabPage();
                        _page.Text = "SF01";
                        _page.Controls.Add(new SF01(_container));

                        break;
                }

                if (_page != null)
                {

                    tapplications.TabPages.Add(_page);
                    m_list.Add(_count, _page);
                    _count++;

                }

            }

            tapplications.TabPages.Add(tlog);

            if (_host.User.Admin)
                tapplications.TabPages.Add(tadmin);

            _container.Controls.Add(this);

        }
```

As you can see `SF01` is my usercontrol.
Now how do I go about loading other usercontrols
by name instead of hard typing the class object?
This way I can create more applications and forget about how to load them. (`case "SF01":`)
All the applications will reside beneath a project folder `applications`, maybe there is a way to iterate through that project folder?

[image: Project]

Comment: If you're trying to quicken development you should pre-define forms that suit your style and create controls that do your extra functionality. Because using strings to load controls is a step backwards in terms of readability and steepens the learning curve.

Comment: I agree but this is not possible (I think) in this case. The user logs in by means of a webservice and the application class gets a list of all the applications the user can run. This all happens in 1 form. I need to find a way to translate the String[] _applications to the user controls types...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

A User Control can be instanciated using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as any other kind of object.

```
string objTypeName = "myNamespace.UI.SF01"; // Full namespace name
SF01 myNewSF01 = (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(objTypeName));
```

Then you can replace your switch statement with

```
_page = new TabPage();
_page.Text = "SF01";

var control = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("myNamespace." + _application));
_page.Controls.Add(control);
```

Comment: Excellent! How should I catch non-existant "applications"?
(nevermind, got around that.)

Comment: + SF01 constructor needs a parameter... :(
What I mean is that SF01 needs a reference to it's container so it can access that object and it's parent (main).

Comment: I've exposed the constructors parameter as a property but still need to find a way to access that types property...?

Comment: I've been looking at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.90).aspx) but my IDE keeps saying `No overload for method 'CreateInstance' takes '2' arguments`... I'm running on Compact 3.5 Framework (Windows CE 5)

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know about Compact 3.5 Framework. But you're on the right track. To solve that Container thing, I would create an interface IMyApplication with a Container member, and make every control like SF01 inherits from it. Then I can put IMyApplication instead of (Control) before CreateInstance, so I can set the container after.

Comment: The interface thing might require too much work :( There is a workaround here to use Activator.CreateInstance with a constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436/compact-framework-how-do-i-dynamically-create-type-with-no-default-constructor

Comment: I agree with that, just solved the problem, thank you Laurent for getting me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

I found a (simpler) [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288310/activator-createinstance-how-to-create-instances-of-classes-that-have-paramete) by using reflection.

```
foreach (String _application in _applications)
            {

                TabPage _page = null;

                Type[] _atypes = new Type[] { typeof(Panel) };
                Object[] _avalues = new Object[] { _container };
                ConstructorInfo _ctor = Type.GetType("SFM." + _application).GetConstructor(_atypes);
                Object _control = _ctor.Invoke(_avalues);

                if (_control != null)
                {
                    _page = new TabPage();
                    _page.Text = _application;
                    _page.Controls.Add((Control)_control);
                }

                if (_page != null)
                {

                    tapplications.TabPages.Add(_page);
                    m_list.Add(_count, _page);
                    _count++;

                }

            }
```

Everything now works as expected!
 Just need to do more error protection (Invoke fail, ...)