# Add controls from Folder to tabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Hope to can help me.
I've been struggling with this for days now :(

I have a winforms project and in the project I have a folder named "Controls" which has 3 controls in it.

Now, what I want to do is read that folder on startup and based on how many User Controls (*.cs files) there are in that folder just add them to tabControl on Form1 as separate tabs.

Each of those UserControls (*.cs files) have a public string with a Name set to them as well as desired ID.

I can add them manually by using this script on startup:

```
            if (((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab.Name == "ReportPupilArchiveTab")
        {
            ((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab.Controls.Add(new Controls.PupilArchiveUpdateControl());
        }
        else if (((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab.Name == "UsercodeMismatchTab")
        {
            ((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab.Controls.Add(new Controls.UserCodeMismatchControl());
        }
        else if (((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab.Name == "DataRestoreTab")
        {
            ((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab.Controls.Add(new Controls.TableRestoreControl());
        }
```

So is there a way to scan a specific folder for controls and then add them to the Form1 tabControl?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you screenshot your form? Because To know Folder controls and 3 controls and tabcontrols are designed..

Comment: Is your question similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20323079/1997232) one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically instantiating specific controls during startup can be done through reflection using the desired namespace if they are in one project folder (which defaults to a new namespace). Assuming they have a standard constructor this works:

```
foreach (var controlType in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == "MyProject.MyControlNamespace")) {
    var constructor = controlType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    if(constructor != null) {
        var control = constructor.Invoke(null);
        //add control to your tabControl here
    }                
}
```

Note Reflecting through the types and using Linq is quite slow, but as it is only done once during startup it should not be a problem.

An alternative without using the namespace is creating a Tag Interface (Empty Interface) and having your Controls implement this interface.

```
interface MyControlTagInterface
{}

class CustomControl : MyControlTagInterface
{
    ...
}
```

And then edting  the where clause for each reflected type:

```
.Where(t => typeof(MyControlTagInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

This can be an advantage if you don't want to limit your controls to one namespace or to one assembly

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what should I put in filepath? I can see that it asks for assembly file however not quite sure how to specify full path to it? Also how will that help as assembly file don't contain any info about controls or any other files in the project :(

Comment: @ArtursKirsis filepath is the path to the assembly file which includes your control. i.e.: "MyProgram\MyPluginFolder\MyTextControl.dll"

Comment: Oh, ok, it's not an actual DLL. My app is just one EXE file and nothing else. So I have a folder called "Controls" in my project and in there I have UserControls (*.cs files) so I need to read those somehow and load dynamically into the form

Comment: ah then my Answer doesn't really apply. If you edit your Question i will edit the answer how to do this easily though using an Tag Interface and selfreflection at startup. At least if I understand it correctly now

Comment: Edited, not quite sure if it makes sense now but that's as close as I can explain it :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work now. Seems that I will be able to modify this code to suit my needs.